# Win32 C/C++ - Detecting if IPv6 is installed

Tags: c++, winapi, networking

Is there a way to detect if the IPv6 protocol is installed without looping through all available IP addresses and checking for IPv6 addresses? I can't find anything on msdn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [WSCEnumProtocols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742237%28VS.85%29.aspx) to detect if IPv6 is available on the machine.